# Take a screenshot with program minimized

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote some code for a program I am making to take a screenshot when the program is minimized. Thing is something is wrong with the code and I am not sure what it is. Whenever I take a screenshot the program is taking the picture with the application up and not minimized.

So what I need it to do is minimize the application then take the screenshot and then reopen the program after its taken the screenshot.

Sorry for the noob question but I am brand new to the VB and only been coding it in for less then a day.

```
    Dim screenImage As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenImage)
    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height))


    Me.Hide()
    screenImage.Save("C:\screenImage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim tSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)
    Dim tSpan2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)
    Do While Math.Abs(tSpan.Subtract(tSpan2).Seconds) < 2
        tSpan2 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)

    Loop
    Me.Show()
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Set the form's Opacity property to 99 and delete the Hide() call.  This is actually a bug :)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Hide` **after** you've taken the screenshot :)

Try this:

```vb
Dim screenImage As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenImage)

Me.Hide()
Me.Application.DoEvents() ' <-- might not be necessary; try without it first.

g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height))

screenImage.Save("C:\screenImage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim tSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)
Dim tSpan2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)
Do While Math.Abs(tSpan.Subtract(tSpan2).Seconds) < 2
    tSpan2 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.DateTime.Now.Second)

Loop
Me.Show()
```

Comment: yea it is still showing the application in the screenshot. :(

Comment: @romkyns I didn't event notice he was taking the screenshot before the hide.  Nice catch.

Comment: @norlando Heh, I also didn't notice that straight away; my first answer also only suggested DoEvents.

Comment: for whatever reason its still showing the application in the screenshot :( i thought it worked but it was behind a folder :(

Comment: @Alex Even with `DoEvents`? Maybe it's time to add delays like suggested by norlando.

Comment: didnt work with the doevents i have no idea wtf is going on with it. i guess i need to figure out what norlando was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the code below after you Me.Hide()

```
Application.DoEvents()
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
```

The sleep 100 should be enough but if the window is still partially there try adding more time.

**Edit:**

Looking at you code I didn't realize you tried to put in a wait.  The Thread.Sleep will do the wait for you.  Just put in the time in milliseconds.

**Option 2:**

Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to take the screenshot.  Just put the Me.Hide before starting the background worker, screen capture in the DoWork and the Me.Show in the RunWorkerCompleted.  Also, put in a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` inside of the DoWork before the screenshot.

Comment: same thing the program is still in the picture.

Comment: it seems the program is taking the picture while the program is up, not when its minimized.

Comment: Another option would be putting the screen capture inside of a background worker. Putting it in a different thread will allow the window to disappear.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Just put the Me.Show inside of the BackroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: How would that look with the code. Sorry I am still learning and really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this when a button is clicked. the screenshot gets into a picturebox called picDisplay.

```
    Me.Hide()
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    picDisplay.Image = screenshot
    Me.Show()
    'this takes a screenshot
```

and then clicking this button saves it:

```
    Dim savefiledialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
    savefiledialog1.Title = "Save File"
    savefiledialog1.FileName = "*.bmp"
    savefiledialog1.Filter = "Bitmap |*.bmp"
    If savefiledialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        picDisplay.Image.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    End If
    'and this saves the screenshot
```