# I want to get Screenshot inside of a window

Tags: c#, window, screenshot

I try to get screen shot from a window, but my window isn't visible (because form in system tray) draw to bitmap isn't work return blank form image? Any idea for my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with program minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856991/take-a-screenshot-with-program-minimized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out [github](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs)

This is implementation using SharpDX

Whether you want to take a screenshot using java you check out the comment
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326/6655179

Comment: I want in java dude